# Define $this variable correct in Magento PHP script

Tags: php, magento, this

I have a unchangeable script, which does not work. But it's possible to add code on the beginning, or at the end.

This is the script:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->setConfigData('general/country/default', 'DE');
$installer->setConfigData('general/country/allow','BE,BG,DK,DE,CY');
$installer->setConfigData('general/country/optional_zip_countries','IE');
$installer->setConfigData('general/country/eu_countries','BE,CY');

$installer->endSetup();
```

If I change the beginning of the script to:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_setup", "core_setup");
$installer->startSetup();
```

It would work, but as I said its not possible to write inside the script. The error, that I receive is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function startSetup() on a non-object
```

Is there a way to make that script working?

It is a Magento script for importing system configuration.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you are executing that code from outside a class member function (and from a class at all).

`$this` variable only makes sense within a class, The second approach works because `$installer` becomes an object after executing `Mage::getModel`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way to open the correct class on the beginning of the script? so that $this works?

Comment: Can't you use $installer = new yourClass() ?

Comment: If I use $installer = new Mage::getModel(); I receive no error anymore, but the script changes nothing.. Am I doing a mistake here?

Comment: What's the flow? If you're saying `$installer = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_setup", "core_setup");` would work, can't you just instead do `$this = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_setup", "core_setup");` to preempt the value of $this?

Comment: I cant get it to work...My class is "Mage" so I could create an object like "$object=new Mage". Now I could do "$object->Mage::getModel("eav/entity_setup","core_setup");" If I use now the $this variable I receive "Error: Using $this when not in object context". But why? I thought my object is declared?

Comment: @mattbryanswan I think you can't define $this like a normal variable (you can but it would not make sense)

Comment: @Vidarrus Depends on the scope. We don't know enough about how you're running this to know. OSdave's answer is how you would typically define it, but if you're not running your install scripts the typical way, that might not help. I would try both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define the class to be used by the setup (aka `$this`) in your module's `config.xml`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <!--other definitions-->
        <resources>
            <namespace_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </namespace_module_setup>
        </resources>
        <!--other definitions-->
    </global>
    <!--other definitions-->
</config>
```